# Error Odatasource editor System.Net.HttpWebresponse

Tags: ssis, odata, etl

Hope someone can help me on this. I've created a SSIS package with `ODatasource` where the feed URL used to work fine couple of days ago. But now it is throwing the following exception:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.HttpWebresponse'.

Anyone encountered this error before? Thanks !

Comment: What is the  datasource link you are using in ODATA connection manager?? Are you using expressions in connection manager or to set some properties?

Comment: also check this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94e688be-d480-4986-bf0b-419c12772f7d/use-odata-to-get-documents-gives-quotcannot-access-a-disposed-objectquot-error?forum=sqlintegrationservices